# Что предпочтительнее и в каких случаях: Scanner или BufferedReader?

Tags: java, scanner

Если долго объяснять - обойдусь ссылками на пояснения)

Comment: Сканер сойдет для школьных/институтских лабораторок. На все остальное есть мастер кард........BufferedReader (и не только)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/37810/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-scanner-console-%D0%B8-bufferedreader

Answer (score 3):

*Сходства:*

могут получать данные из текстового файла.

*Различия:*

- Экземпляры класса ***java.io*.BufferedReader** предназначены для чтения потока символов с буферизацией (символов, массивов и строк).
- Экземпляры класса ***java.util*.Scanner** предназначены для разбора данных на составляющие с учетом форматов, шаблонов, разных разделителей.
  Входные данные для Scanner могут быть файлы, потоки байтов, потоки символов, строки.