# Проверка вводимых данных BufferedReader

Tags: java, io, scanner

Начал изучать джаву. Добрался до ввода с консоли. Есть два способа, ну или я нашёл только два: сканер и буферридер.
Со сканером вроде разобрался, там можно проверить вводимые данные с помощью методов hasNext...()
Например, что введен инт можно так вот проверить:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       if (sc.hasNextInt()) 
           int number = sc.nextInt();
       else 
           System.out.println("Не число.");
```

Только там вместо sout надо "бросать исключения", но в этом я ещё не разобрался пока.

А что делать с буферридером? Как его проверять? Читал что-то про "обрабатывать исключения" не совсем понял, как уже писал выше
Может кто-то может на примере написать правильный код, например, для ввода интового значения. Я так понимаю, что проверить нужно на не пустоту и тип инт?

Answer (score 1):

В Java есть [3 способа](https://data-flair.training/blogs/read-java-console-input/) чтения входных данных из консоли:

- использование Bufferedreader класса;
- использование Scanner класса;
- использование Console класса.

Разницу можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/37823/260756) и [здесь](https://data-flair.training/blogs/read-java-console-input/).

[Код с примерами использования](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/io/java-io-how-to-read-input-from-console/) всех способов:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleInputExamples
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      usingConsoleReader();
      usingBufferedReader();
      usingScanner();
   }

   private static void usingConsoleReader()
   {
      Console console = null;
      String inputString = null;
      try
      {
         // cоздать объект console
         console = System.console();
         // если console не равен null
         if (console != null)
         {
            // прочитать строку из пользовательского ввода
            inputString = console.readLine("Name: ");
            // вывод строки
            System.out.println("Name entered : " + inputString);
         }
      } catch (Exception ex)
      {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private static void usingBufferedReader()
   {
      System.out.println("Name: ");
      try{
         BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         String inputString = bufferRead.readLine();

         System.out.println("Name entered : " + inputString);
     }
     catch(IOException ex)
     {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
   }

   private static void usingScanner()
   {
      System.out.println("Name: ");

      Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
      String inputString = scanIn.nextLine();

      scanIn.close();            
      System.out.println("Name entered : " + inputString);
   }   
}
```

[Одно из основных отличий](https://www.java67.com/2016/06/5-difference-between-bufferedreader-and-scanner-in-java.html) между BufferedReader и классом Scanner заключается в том, что первый класс предназначен только для чтения строковых или текстовых данных, тогда как класс Scanner предназначен как для чтения, так и для анализа текстовых данных в примитивных типах Java, таких как int, short, float, double и long.

BufferedReader может только String читать, а Scanner может читать как String, так и другие типы данных, такие как int, float, long, double, float и т.д.

Таким образом, [BufferedReader не предоставляет напрямую методов для чтения integer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-integers-from-a-file-using-bufferedreader-in-java) введённого пользователем. Можно использовать метод readLine(), однако изначально придется считывать integer в формате String.

В случае с методом parseInt(), он принимает String значение, парсит его как десятичный integer и возвращает.

Answer (score 0):

Если числа пишутся каждое в своей строке то можно использовать такой способ

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int i;
try
{
  i = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
}
```

метод readLine возвращает строку введенную в консоли, а метод parseInt возвратит число, если строка которую передают как параметр соответствует формату числа. Иначе он вызовет исключение NumberFormatException. Но этот метод довольно капризный, даже пробел в начале строки помешает получить число.